# Getting error with turtle.bgcolor() in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use turtle to create a square, while tryng to give a color to the turtle window a color "black". I am getting errors, any input will be helpful.

Below is my code:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
window = turtle._Screen
window.bgcolor("black")


brad = turtle.Turtle()
brad.forward(100)
window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

Below is what I get in error:

```
color = self._bgcolor(color)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_bgcolor'
```

Answer (score 0):

`turtle._Screen` gives you the `Screen` **class**, not a Screen **object**. Use [`turtle.getscreen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.getscreen) instead.

Answer (score 0):

General issues with your code:

Don't access methods, or variables, whose names begin with underscore "_".  These are internal methods and not for you, if you're new to this library.  Find high level methods in the documentation.

If you set the background color to black, you need to change the pen color, otherwise you're drawing a black square on a black background and it won't be visible.

Don't call window methods in a function called `draw_square()` -- it shouldn't know the state of the screen in order to draw a square.  Handle these details outside of the function.

Here's a rework of your code along following the above guidelines:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    brad = turtle.Turtle()

    brad.pencolor("white")

    for _ in range(4):
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("black")

draw_square()

window.exitonclick()
```